# Why can't resolve NaN in Selenium script?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, selenium-ide

I have recorded some functions using Selenium IDE and exported test into java file. I have used "wait for element visible" condition when performing action in order to assert a notification.

When I run the script through Selenium ide everything works perfectly but when I convert to java file it shows me an error for NaN.

[image: Image of IDE]

Here is the code

```
{
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, NaN);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("my xpath")));
}
assertThat(driver.findElement(By.xpath("my xpath")).getText(), is("Request for registration successfully submitted."));
```

}

How do I resolve this Nan issue?
[image: Code image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Selenium documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html#WebDriverWait-org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver-long-), this constructor for WebDriverWait requires a long as second argument - the *timeOutInSeconds*.

In Java, when *NaN* is used in arithmetic operations, [the behavior is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2618081/2252076).

You simply need to use some timeout value instead of NaN when creating the *WebDriverWait* object.